# Define a keyword to replace a long url

Tags: html, css, url, tags

To create download button I normally use:

```
<button><a href="url-to-the-file"></a></button>
```

Is there any way to define **myfile = url-to-the-file** so that I can use just:

```
<button><a href="myfile"></a></button>
```

Comment: If you can use php, then in a common file, set a variable `$myfile`, and then change your link to `<a href="<?php echo $myfile; ?>">`.

Comment: I am assuming you are using a PHP-enabled server, of course.

Comment: You could do it with JavaScript. Make a lookup of some sort using an object literal, and then return the "real" URL. It's not clear what benefit you are hoping to achieve, though.

Comment: @frenchDolphin I am new to html. I am now constructing a blogger webpage. I am not sure if the provided server is PHP-enabled or not.

Comment: @GregPettit: I want to place a list of long and messy URLs somewhere. And I will use it in the body part with as short as possible command or tag.

Comment: Markup only needs to be semantic and readable. If you just use the full link in the normal way, anybody reading your markup will see the `href` attribute and understand that no matter how long and cumbersome the link inside, that it's a link, period. If anything, long-term maintenance is HARDER because with the substitution method, you or anyone maintaining that code will need to understand the system. Plus you may have to debug a click handler some day. HREF does what it needs to do, and it does it just fine, with no extra overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but for example you could replace the short text with the real links fairly easily. Just as a very basic example (http://jsfiddle.net/7vbv9oxc/):

HTML:

```
<button>
  <a href="googs">Click</a>
</button>
```

JS:

```
var links = {
    googs: "http://google.com"
}

// jQuery but vanilla JS shouldn't be hard
$('a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var shortLink = $this.attr('href');
    if(typeof(links[shortLink]) !== "undefined") {
        $this.attr('href', links[shortLink]);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could do the substitution at click time, saving iterating over all the anchor tags.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var shortLink = $this.attr('href');
    if(typeof(links[shortLink]) !== "undefined") {
        $this.attr('href', links[shortLink]);
    }
});
```

We don't prevent default (or return false) because we WANT it to act like a normal anchor, but after the swap has been made. If you want to do something different before loading or redirecting the target URL, you would add an `e.preventDefault()` to that code block.

*Note (for my own peace of mind!) that none of this code is meant to represent optimizations or best practices; it's just meant to illustrate the idea. For example, you would probably want to put the click listener on an ancestor!*

Comment: Can we just shorten it like **<downloadbutoon href="googs">**

Comment: There's a lot you can do that depends on your target browsers. ;) My impulse would be to do `<button class="download" data-link="googs">text</button>` if you are allowed to target browsers that allow data attributes.